# Extract first instance of value for specific key with sed

Tags: string, sed, extract

From this string (sanitized), I'm trying to extract the first instance of the `"id"` from this payload (formatted here, but is actually all on one line):

```
{
    "result": [{
        "id": "a4e2a4682e286dea803aaa4d2aff851212c3",
        "name": "test.com",
        "status": "active",
        "paused": false,
        "type": "partial",
        "development_mode": 0,
        "verification_key": "12312312-123123",
        "original_name_servers": ["dns1.test.com", "dns2.test.com"],
        "original_registrar": null,
        "original_dnshost": "register",
        "modified_on": "2017-02-24T17:59:59.080278Z",
        "created_on": "2017-01-31T20:27:03.395683Z",
        "meta": {
            "step": 4,
            "wildcard_proxiable": false,
            "custom_certificate_quota": 0,
            "page_rule_quota": 3,
            "phishing_detected": false,
            "multiple_railguns_allowed": false
        },
        "owner": {
            "type": "organization",
            "id": "12312123123",
            "name": "Test"
        },
        "permissions": ["#analytics:read", "#billing:edit", "#billing:read", "#cache_purge:edit", "#dns_records:edit", "#dns_records:read", "#lb:edit", "#lb:read", "#logs:read", "#organization:edit", "#organization:read", "#ssl:edit", "#ssl:read", "#waf:edit", "#waf:read", "#zone:edit", "#zone:read", "#zone_settings:edit", "#zone_settings:read"],
        "plan": {
            "id": "0feeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee",
            "name": "Free Website ",
            "price ": 0,
            "currency ": "USD ",
            "frequency ": "",
            "is_subscribed ": true,
            "can_subscribe ": false,
            "legacy_id ": "free ",
            "legacy_discount ": false,
            "externally_managed ": false
        }
    }],
    "result_info": {
        "page": 1,
        "per_page ": 20,
        "total_pages": 1,
        "count ": 1,
        "total_count ": 1
    },
    "success ": true,
    "errors ": [],
    "messages ": []
}
```

using following sed statement:

```
`echo $txtauthkey | sed -e 's/^.*"id"[ ]*:[ ]*"//' -e 's/".*//'`
```

but it extracts the last instance of `"id"`, ie `"0feeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a *reluctant* quantifier `.*?` rather than a greedy one `.*`. Unfortunately, no flavour of `sed` supports reluctant quantifier, but `perl` does:

```
`echo $txtauthkey | perl -pe 's/^.*?"id" *: *"//;s/".*//'
```

- `.*` consumes as *much* as possible - all the way to the *last* `'"id"`
- `.*?` consumes as *little* as possible - which will stop at the *first* `'"id"'

Comment: @DaveA The way to thank here is to accept the answer that worked.

Comment: By the way, i think you can avoid the sed in the end by using `perl -pe 's/^.*?"id" *: *"//';s/".*//'` . I think perl can do the trick

Comment: Yeap. Perl has been seen able to apply sequential substitutions on the previously transformed text, something that sed can also not to do

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to it, this is very simple with the JSON parser [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/):

```
$ jq -r '.result[0].id' infile.json
a4e2a4682e286dea803aaa4d2aff851212c3
```

With sed, you could reverse the input and extract the last instance of `"value":"di"` and reverse it again:

```
$ rev infile.json | sed 's/.*"\([^"]*\)"[[:blank:]]*:[[:blank:]]*"di".*/\1/' | rev
a4e2a4682e286dea803aaa4d2aff851212c3
```

And with sed and nothing else, I can't think of anything better than shaving of characters from the beginning of the string until it starts with `"id"`:

```
$ sed ':a;/^id"/{s/id"[[:blank:]]*:[[:blank:]]*"\([^"]*\).*/\1/;q};s/[^"]*"//;ba' infile.json
a4e2a4682e286dea803aaa4d2aff851212c3
```

More readable:

```
:a          # Label to branch to
/^id"/ {    # If the line starts with id"
    # Extract value of "id" key
    s/id"[[:blank:]]*:[[:blank:]]*"\([^"]*\).*/\1/
    q       # Quit - we are done
}
s/[^"]*"//  # Remove characters up and including next double quote
ba          # Branch to label
```